# Why is my default browser setting being ignored

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I have set & reset and checked that Chrome is my default browser, yet on some links in emails, Edge starts.

Why is that?

Comment: How are you setting it exactly?

Answer (score 1):

First Check if Chrome is set as default for all protocols. Navigate to Control Panel → Programs → Default programs. Choose the first option that says Set your default programs.

Select Google Chrome and click on set this programs as default.

[image]

Also make sure that Google Chrome is set as default app for emails. Go to Settings → System → Default apps and set Chrome as default for emails.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. However, after having a closer look, it turned out, that

- https-URLs opened in Edge and
- http-URLs  opened in the defined default browser.

Solution was as follows:

1. Go to "All Control Panel Items\Default Programs\Set Default Programs"
2. Select the desired default browser
3. Click "Choose defaults for this program" (bottom of window)
4. Tick HTTPS

Looks like a bug to me that "Choose a default browser" does not affect the HTTPS setting.

It's impertinent that on rolling out major updates Microsoft change user's defaults.